Kotlin Multiplatform library: specific iOS development with Kotlin, Swift, Cocoapods and Interoperability with Objective-C
I would like to know if all of these scenarios are possible right now and the way to do it, both for a Kotlin Multiplatform project with Compose and also for a Kotlin Multiplatform library without UI targeting JVM, Android and iOS that will be published in a GitLab's Maven repository.
I need help with points 3, 4 and 5

To have an specific iOS implementation using iOS default platform APIs with Kotlin -> It works with the default KMP project templates with no tweaks.
To have an specific iOS implementation using iOS default platform APIs with Swift -> It works, it can be published and consumed, the only thing to be worried is that it must be Objective-C compatible and you must create the headers for it or use third party tools to do so (I`ve used Swift Klib Plugin)
To have an specific iOS implementation using an Objective-C compatible cocoapods library -> It works fine if used by the project itself, once its published as a library the project using the library will give an error (I guess I'm missing something for the cocoapods dependency linking...):

Ld .../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/KotlinProject.app/KotlinProject normal (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
    cd ...CmpWithKmpLib/iosApp/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Xlinker -reproducible -target arm64-apple-ios15.3-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.5.sdk -O0 -L.../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator -L.../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator -F.../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator -F.../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator -F.../CmpWithKmpLib/iosApp/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.5 -F.../CmpWithKmpLib/iosApp/../composeApp/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.5 -filelist .../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/KotlinProject.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker .../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/KotlinProject_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker .../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/KotlinProject.swiftmodule -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker .../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/KotlinProject.app-Simulated.xcent -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __ents_der -Xlinker .../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/KotlinProject.app-Simulated.xcent.der -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker .../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/KotlinProject_dependency_info.dat -o .../CmpWithKmpLib/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/KotlinProject.app/KotlinProject

ld: warning: search path '.../CmpWithKmpLib/iosApp/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.5' not found

ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'AFNetworking': framework 'AFNetworking' not found

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
       in ComposeApp[2721](libcom.foo:kmplibdemo-cache.a.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


To have an specific iOS implementation using an Objective-C cocoapods compatible library inside a Swift file -> Coudln't get it to work with the approach used in the second point, the cocoapods import is not resolved, probably because the cocoapods library is loaded only for iosMain and the Swift files can only access platform dependencies, is there a way to do this?
To have an specific iOS implementation using an Pure Swift cocoapods library inside a Swift file and create wrappers for Objective-C -> Is this possible and how?

library's build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
    alias(libs.plugins.swiftklib)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinCocoapods)
    id("module.publication")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            val jvm = JvmTarget.fromTarget(libs.versions.jvm.get())
            jvmTarget.set(jvm)
        }
    }
    androidTarget {
        publishLibraryVariants("release")
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            val jvm = JvmTarget.fromTarget(libs.versions.jvm.get())
            jvmTarget.set(jvm)
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.compilations {
            val main by getting {
                cinterops {
                    create("swift")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cocoapods {
        summary = "foo"
        version = "1.0.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "16.0"
        framework {
            baseName = "kmplibdemo"
            isStatic = true
            freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-Xbinary=bundleId=com.foo.kmplibdemo")
        }
        pod("AFNetworking", "~> 4.0")
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                //put your multiplatform dependencies here
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.foo.kmplibdemo"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
    }
    compileOptions {
        val javaVersion = JavaVersion.toVersion(libs.versions.jvm.get())
        sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
        targetCompatibility = javaVersion
    }
}


swiftklib {
    create("swift") {
        path = file("src/iosMain/swift")
        packageName("com.foo.kmplibdemo.swift")
    }
}

module.publication.gradle.kts
plugins {
    `maven-publish`
    signing
}

publishing {
    // Configure all publications
    publications.withType<MavenPublication> {
        // Stub javadoc.jar artifact
        artifact(tasks.register("${name}JavadocJar", Jar::class) {
            archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
            archiveAppendix.set(this@withType.name)
        })
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://git.foo.com/api/v4/projects/757/packages/maven")
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials::class) {
                name = "Deploy-Token"
                value = extra["gitlabDeployToken"] as String
            }

            authentication {
                create("header", HttpHeaderAuthentication::class)
            }
        }
    }
}

